# How to make website embeds in Discord that have a profile picture and a footer like tweet embeds?

Tags: html, web, twitter, discord, embed

I've been trying to find the meta tags for these parts of Tweets embeds (see image), to share nice embeds from my forum, that would include a profile picture next to the author name and a posting date in the footer.

[Discord embed of a tweet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye867.png)

Does anyone know how too add a small rounded profile picture and a footer in a website Discord embed, like a tweet?

These questions are similar but answers don't include anything about these parts of the embed :

[How to create own embed site for Discord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59335731/how-to-create-own-embed-site-for-discord)

[How to make my website urls to generate nice embedded pills in social apps (Discord, Twitter, ...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71278032/how-to-make-my-website-urls-to-generate-nice-embedded-pills-in-social-apps-disc)

Here is the current code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title><%= title %></title>
<meta name="description" content="<%= description %>"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="<%= icon %>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<%= link %>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<%= title+'B' %>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta data-react-helmet="true" name="theme-color" content="<%= '#'+color %>"/>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And how it's embedded in Discord :
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJeLr.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the profile picture using `embed.set_author(icon_url="Image url here"` or `embed.set_thumbnail(url="url"`
To make the footer, you do just that using `embed.set_footer(name="footer")`